# Powermock with Mockito - dependencies issue

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock

I am using following dependencies:

- mockito-core: 2.8.47
- powermock-api-mockito2: 2.0.2
- powermock-module-junit4: 2.0.2

And this is my pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
  <version>${powermock.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
  <version>${powermock.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

with following properties:

```
<properties>
  <powermock.version>2.0.2</powermock.version>
</properties>
```

Now when I am running some unit test I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.MockitoFramework.getPlugins()Lorg/mockito/plugins/MockitoPlugins;
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.mockmaker.MockMakerLoader.doLoad(MockMakerLoader.java:45)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.mockmaker.MockMakerLoader.load(MockMakerLoader.java:36)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.<init>(PowerMockMaker.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
```

I am bit lost in this - still getting same scenario: changing version of one of dependencies and something is missing :/

I was using this site to choose dependencies versions: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito-2-Maven
Can someone help me and tell what is procedure for choosing proper artifacts with versions?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2):

when you add any dependencies, do check  complied dependencies that will get added

for ex - if you are adding  powermock-api-mockito version - 1.7.4

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito2/2.0.2

Always choose a stable version and most used version, which you did correctly , go to above url and see as shown below

[image]

scroll down on page - you will see that it is automatically adding - below dependancies

[image]

Now I think it is easy for you to find out dependencies.

**Note - here  it shows different version of**

**mockito-core: 2.8.47  -->  2.23.0**